# Circular import Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, circular-dependency

I have a problem in my Python 3.6 code regarding circular import.

I have a base class called Cereal and 4 classes that inherit from it (Cereal1, Cereal2,...). Each is a different file. For example:

File1:

```
class Cereal:
```

File2:

```
class Cereal1(Cereal):
```

And so on. When I create a cereal:

```
x = Cereal(K1,K2)
```

depending on the K1 and K2 values, a function inside the constructor recognises which type of cereal it is and changes the class of the cereal:

```
def __init__(self, K1, K2):
    self.findcerealtype(K1, K2)

def findcerealtype(self, K1, K2):
    if K1 < 0:
        self.__class__ = Cereal1
        self = Cereal1(K1, K2)
    elif K1 == 0:
        self.__class__  = Cereal2
        self = Cereal2(K1, K2)
    else:
        if K2 < 1:
            self.__class__  = Cereal3
            self = Cereal3(K1, K2)
        else:
            self.__class__  = Cereal4
            self = Cereal4(K1, K2)
```

Well, the problem arises when I import the files as the following:

File1:

```
from File2 import Cereal1
from File3 import Cereal2
from File4 import Cereal3
from File5 import Cereal4

class Cereal:
    def __init__(self,K1,K2):
        findcerealtype(self,K1,K2)

    def findcerealtype(self, K1, K2):
    .
    .
    .and other functions
```

File2:

```
from File1 import Cereal

class Cereal1(Cereal):
    def __init__(self, K1, K2):
    .
    .
    .and other functions
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Cereal'
```

From what I have read I think the problem is the circular imports. I have tried different imports (i.e import File1) and to import the files later on in the code but none of these seem to work.

I have also read that circular import should not happen and that the problem is the way my code is structured. In that case I am open to suggestions on how to rewrite the code but I have no idea on how to do it by myself.

If you managed to read until the end, thank you very much and I hope you can help me!

Comment: I would highly recommend using a factory function that calls the correct constructor based on `K1` and `K2` instead of attempting to change the type during initialization.

Comment: you have a more serious problem with the initialization logic, if `Cereal1` inherits from `Cereal` then it's constructor will (if you are doing it correctly) call `Cereal.__init__` so your `Cereal` constructor calls `findcerealtype` which calls a specific constructor which calls `Cereal.__init__` for a new object -> you have infinite recursion.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I may have not understood you. The object is created from the base class Cereal, and its constructor calls the function that determines which type of cereal the object is. But the cereal subclass constructor does not call the base class (at least that is what I think, inside that constructor there is no call to Cereal.__init__). The program works in a single file, but when I divided it in different files is when it gives me the error. Maybe with an example I can understand you better. Thanks for the answer!